# NLTK Stopword List

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I have the code beneath and I am trying to apply a stop word list to list of words.  However the results still show words such as "a" and "the" which I thought would have been removed by this process.  Any ideas what has gone wrong would be great .

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

word_list = open("xxx.y.txt", "r")
filtered_words = [w for w in word_list if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
print filtered_words
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopword removal with NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A few things of note.

- If you are going to be checking membership against a list over and over, I would use a set instead of a list.
- `stopwords.words('english')` returns a list of **lowercase** stop words. It is quite likely that your source has capital letters in it and is not matching for that reason.
- You aren't reading the file properly, you are checking over the file object not a list of the words split by spaces.

Putting it all together:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

word_list = open("xxx.y.txt", "r")
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))

for line in word_list:
    for w in line.split():
        if w.lower() not in stops:
            print w
```

Comment: Note that you still aren't filtering for punctuation, you'll want to remove things like `';"{}[]/?.,!` for example.

Comment: brilliant that worked, must have been reading over the file incorrectly, thanks.