# Unique word frequency using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, token

Code to get the unique Word Frequency for the following using NLTK.

`Seq Sentence` 
`1   Let's try to be Good.`
`2   Being good doesn't make sense.`
`3   Good is always good.`

Output:
`{'good':3, 'let':1, 'try':1, 'to':1, 'be':1, 'being':1, 'doesn':1, 't':1, 'make':1, 'sense':1, 'is':1, 'always':1, '.':3, ''':2, 's':1}`

Answer (score 6):

If you are very particular about using nltk you the refer the following code snippet

```
import nltk

text1 = '''Seq Sentence 
1   Let's try to be Good.
2   Being good doesn't make sense.
3   Good is always good.'''

words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text1)
fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(words)

filtered_word_freq = dict((word, freq) for word, freq in fdist1.items() if not word.isdigit())

print(filtered_word_freq)
```

Hope it helps.

Referred some parts from:

[How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

[Dropping specific words out of an NLTK distribution beyond stopwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826950/dropping-specific-words-out-of-an-nltk-distribution-beyond-stopwords?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import nltk

sno = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
s = "1   Let's try to be Good. 2   Being good doesn't make sense. 3   Good is always good."
s1 = s.split(' ')
d = pd.DataFrame(s1)
s2 = d[0].apply(lambda x: sno.stem(x))
counts =  Counter(s2)
print(counts)
```

Output will be:

```
Counter({'': 6, 'be': 2, 'good.': 2, 'good': 2, '1': 1, 'let': 1, 'tri': 1, 'to': 1, '2': 1, "doesn't": 1, 'make': 1, 'sense.': 1, '3': 1, 'is': 1, 'alway': 1})
```