# How to elimate stopwords in this code?

Tags: python, nltk

I have written code to do Sentiment Analysis, therefore I use two different dictionaries in which sentences are tagges as negative oder positive. My code snippet so far Looks like this:

```
def format_sentence(sentence):
     return {word: True for word in word_tokenize(satz) }

pos_data = []
with open('Positiv.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pos_data.append([format_sentence(line), 'pos'])

neg_data = []
with open('Negativ.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       neg_data.append([format_sentence(line), 'neg'])

training_data = pos_data[:3] +  neg_data[:3]
test_data = pos_data[3:] + neg_data[3:]

model = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_data)
```

Now I would like the code to elimate all Stopwords from the sentences in the dictionary but I don't know how to implement that into my code as I am a beginner in Python programming. 
I would be very thankful if anyone could help me with this :)

Comment: What is a "stopword", and how do you define "elimination"?

Comment: stopwords are words like 'and', 'but' and so on. I want the Classifier to not include These kinds of words in the Training data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopword removal with NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the Naive Bayes Classifier implementation in NLTK. NLTK also has built in stopword lists for some languages.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops = stopwords.words('english')

def format_sentence(sentence):
    return {word: True for word in word_tokenize(sentence) if word not in stops}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use only python lists, try this template of code, which creates a new list with deleted stopwords:

```
list_without_stopwords = [word for word in original_list if word not in stopword_list]
```