# Regex for unicode sentences without spaces using CountVectorizer

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, vectorization, tokenize

I hope I don't have to provide an example set.

I have a 2D array where each array contains a set of words from sentences.

I am using a [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to effectively call `fit_transform` on the whole 2D array, such that I can build a vocabulary of words.

However, I have sentences like:

```
u'Besides EU nations , Switzerland also made a high contribution at Rs 171 million LOCATION_SLOT~-nn+nations~-prep_besides nations~-prep_besides+made~prep_at made~prep_at+rs~num rs~num+NUMBER_SLOT'
```

And my current vectorizer is too strict at removing things like `~` and `+` as tokens. Whereas I want it to see each word in terms of `split()` a token in the vocab, i.e. `rs~num+NUMBER_SLOT` should be a word in itself in the vocab, as should `made`. At the same time, stopwords like `the` the `a` (the normal stopwords set) should be removed.

Current vectorizer:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer="word",stop_words=None,tokenizer=None,preprocessor=None,max_features=5000)
```

You can specify a `token_pattern` but I am not sure which one I could use to achieve my aims. Trying:

```
token_pattern="[^\s]*"
```

Leads to a vocabulary of:

```
{u'': 0, u'p~prep_to': 3764, u'de~dobj': 1107, u'wednesday': 4880, ...}
```

Which messes things up as `u''` is not something I want in my vocabulary.

What is the right token pattern for this type of `vocabulary_` I want to build?

Comment: may be wordpunct_tokenize?? http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html

Comment: That is awesome, do any of these have a remove stopwords option? I basically have to split the string on whitespace (super easy), and then remove any stopwords identified in the tokens. The sequence does matter though I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133088/1168680

Comment: I need to replicate the CountVectorizer, because I need to obtain float representations of each sentence. I need the `vocabulary_` methodology of the scikit learn vectorizer to fit a vocab to all my sentences, and then return for each sentence something like `[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 ]`.  Perhaps I can call the `WhiteSpaceTokenizer` somehow in the `tokenizer` argument? The `CountVectorizer` has a remove stopwords verrsion, hence I think its the best version, I'm just getting this whitespace removal wrong (it is allowing in `u' '`).

Comment: How/why? The CountVectorizer already deals with stopwords which is great,it just needs the right string pattern to split on. The problem here is the regex pattern. For some reason `token_pattern="[^\s]*"` as an argument is letting in `u''`. Edited the question so clearer.

Comment: I think there is some other issue for `u'': 0` you are getting count as 0.

Comment: That isn't the count, it's the dictionary index created for the vocabulary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122644/discussion-between-ravi-and-dhruv-ghulati).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out. The vectorizer was allowing 0 or more non-whitespace items - it should allow 1 or more. The correct `CountVectorizer` is:

```
CountVectorizer(analyzer="word",token_pattern="[\S]+",tokenizer=None,preprocessor=None,stop_words=None,max_features=5000)
```