# How to Determine the Least Important Word to the Meaning of a Sentence

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, nltk

Is there any algorithm or way you could think of to determine the least important word to the meaning of a sentence? **More generally, is there any way to assign some number to each word based on its importance in a sentence?** By "importance" I mean that if you were to remove this word from the sentence it would have little effect to the meaning (low importance) or a large effect to the meaning (high importance).

Comment: What is your definition of *importance* here? Are you trying to say that if you were to remove the word, the sentence could still be understood?

Comment: @idjaw I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very vague question. From what I understand, you want to do something like keyword extraction.

**POS Tagging** is a good start. It lets you tag sentences to their parts of speech (Nouns, verbs adjectives etc) - [POS Tag NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html). You can then write your own rules to extract just the parts of speech that interest you.

[**Stopword Removal**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133088/4098013) is another option

**[Keyword Extraction](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html)** does a bunch of stuff you can read with examples -

1. chunking
2. chinking
3. named entity recognition
4. Building CFGs and parse trees
5. Relation Extraction

I think reading this chapter will give the perspective and the code snippets to get you started.