# Remove stopwords with nltk.corpus from list with lists

Tags: nltk, stop-words

I have a list containing lists with all seperated words of a review, that looks like this:

```
texts = [['fine','for','a','night'],['it','was','good']]
```

I want to remove all stopwords, using the nltk.corpus package, and put all the words without stopwords back into the list. The end results should be a list, consisting of a lists of words without stopwords. This it was I tried:

```
import nltk
nltk.download() # to download stopwords corpus
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords=stopwords.words('english')
words_reviews=[]

for review in texts:
    wr=[]
    for word in review:
        if word not in stopwords:
            wr.append(word)
        words_reviews.append(wr)
```

This code actually worked, but now I get the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words', referring to stopwords. I made sure that I installed all packages. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which line of code causes this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you redefine `stopwords` in your code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords=stopwords.words('english')
```

After the first line, `stopwords` is a corpus reader with a `words()` method. After the second line, it is a list. Proceed accordingly.

Actually looking things up in a list is really slow, so you'll get much better performance if you use this:

```
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`[word for word in text_tokens if not word in stopwords.words()]`

use

```
[word for word in text_tokens if not word in all_stopwords]
```

[image: After stopwords.word('english') the type of the file changes and therefore none of the previous attributes will work]

Answer (score 0):

i removed the set , it worked, may be you could try the same