# A program that counts specific stings in a text, such like "climate finance"

Tags: python, count, cpu-word

```
from collections import Counter
input = 'file.txt'

CounterWords = {}
words = {}
with open(input,'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    word_list = line.replace(',','').replace('\'','').replace('.','').lower().split()
    for word in word_list:
      if len(word) < 6
          continue
      elif word not in CounterWords:
          CounterWords[word] = 1
      else:
          CounterWords[word] = CounterWords[word] + 1
N = 50

top_words = Counter(CounterWords).most_common(N)
for word, frequency in top_words:
    print("%s %d" % (word, frequency))
```

At the moment i am able two select the most frequent words with strings more than X characters.

The program should screen the text and count words like:

"climate finance"
"market failure"
"Paris 2015"

Amount of minimum characters per single string should be still included to prevent results such as "I and".

Comment: get `word_list[i:i+1]` and work with this.

Comment: maybe first you should remove all short words - so called "stopwords". You can use stopwords from module [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/). See: [Stopword removal with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk)

Comment: "get word_list[i:i+1]" looks easy. Where do i have to put it? Within the loop or at the beginning?

Comment: create new for-loop `for i in range(len(word_list)-1): word_list[i:i+1]`

Comment: I do: `for word in range(len(word_list)-1): word_list[word:word+1]` (instead of `for word in word_list:` from the original code above (line 9) I got a error for the next line `if len(word) < 6:` -> **TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()**

Comment: you are wrong. I used name `i` because it keeps index to `word_list`, not word. You have two words in `first, second = word_list[i:i+1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `your_file_content.count(your_string)` :

```
from collections import Counter
input = 'D:\\file.txt'

import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    # "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)  

CounterWords = {}
CounterPairs = {}
words = {}
file_content = ''
with open(input,'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='ignore') as fh:
  file_content = fh.read().replace('\n', ' ')
  word_list = file_content.replace(',','').replace('\'','').replace('.','').lower().split()
  word_list = list(dict.fromkeys(word_list)) # to remove duplicates
  word_pairs_list = pairwise(word_list)
  for word in word_list:
    if len(word) < 6:
      continue
    else:
      CounterWords[word] = file_content.count(word)
  for pair in word_pairs_list:
    CounterPairs[pair] = file_content.count(' '.join(pair))
N = 50

# for all single words :
top_words = Counter(CounterWords).most_common(N)
for word, frequency in top_words:
  print("%s %d" % (word, frequency))

# for all pairs :
top_pairs = Counter(CounterPairs).most_common(N)
for pair, frequency in top_pairs:
  print("%s %d" % (pair, frequency))

# for specific pairs :
print("\n%s %d" % ('climate finance', CounterPairs[('climate', 'finance')]))
```

`pairwise` function taken from : [Iterate a list as pair (current, next) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5434936/4374588)

Comment: thx I am interested in a generic code. At the moment i do not know to which terms are the appear heavily. Do you have an idea?

Comment: what do you mean by terms ? is "Paris 2015" a term ?, you called them words in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: I screen a document with 100000 words and i want to know: First, analyse which words (i.e. "climate"), second which word-pairs (i.e. "climate finance") are the most common in the text.

Comment: First, use nltk as @furas suggested. Second, make sure to properly generate single and pair words. Finally, use `.count()` and `Counter` to analyse all this.

Comment: some help for generating pair words from a list of words : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5434936/4374588

Comment: what i get is **(current item, next item)**, but i want to see the frequency of specific word pairs that belong together to each other (i. e. "climate finance")

Comment: Example: When i am running the loop `for word in word_list: if len(word) < 6: ...` -> The loop should count word pairs  that appear multiple times and merge the two words to one sting. Does someon now a trick?

Comment: you just do the same thing you did for single words using `' '.join((current_item, next_item))` and append it to `sentences_to_be_counted`

Comment: now, the code in my (edited) answer works fine for single and pairs. don't forget to correctly remove stopword and such from your `word_list` instead of testing if length < 6.