# How to retrieve the main intent of a sentence using spacy or nltk?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, pos-tagger, dependency-parsing

**I have a use case where I want to extract main meaningful part of the sentence using spacy or nltk or any NLP libraries.**

**Example sentence1:** "How Can I raise my voice against harassment"
**Intent would be:** "raise voice against harassment"

**Example sentence2:** "Donald Duck is created by which cartoonist/which man/whom ?"
**Intent would be:** "Donald duck is created by"

**Example sentence3:** "How to retrieve the main intent of a sentence using spacy or nltk" ?
**Intent:** "retrieve main intent of sentence using spacy nltk"

I am new to dependency parsing and don't exactly know how to do this. Please help me.

Comment: It is not clear what you can intent. In the industry, intent is associated with multiple phrase that describe the same intention. Here you seems to want to extract a noun phrase. The question is under specified.

Answer (score 13):

## TL;DR

You have to define the ultimate task you want to perform and define what exactly is "intent" / "main information" or "meaning of text".

## In Long

From first look, it seems like you're asking to solve a natural language problem magically. But lets look at the question and what you're really asking, lets avoid all the notion of intent/labels or language (for a while) and just look at what's the in-/output:

```
[in]:  "How Can I raise my voice against harassment"
[out]: "raise voice against harassment"

[in]:  "Donald Duck is created by which cartoonist/which man/whom ?" 
[out]: "Donald duck is created by"

[in]:  "How to retrieve the main intent of a sentence using spacy or nltk ?" 
[out]: "retrieve main intent of sentence using spacy nltk"
```

It seems like all your output tokens/words are just a quote from your input, in that case what if you simply treat your problem as a "span/sequence annotation" task, i.e.

```
[in]:  "How Can I raise my voice against harassment"
[out]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] 

[in]:  "Donald Duck is created by which cartoonist/which man/whom ?" 
[out]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

[in]:  "How to retrieve the main intent of a sentence using spacy or nltk ?" 
[out]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Assuming that each word is a binary label, the output should label `1` for the words that you want to extract from the input and `0` for the ones you don't.

Now given it's a simple binary sequence labeling task, one could simply do:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=sequence+labeling+pytorch
- https://www.google.com/search?q=sequence+labeling+tensorflow

But step back a little,

- Is that really true that an intent be always part of the input?
- What exactly is an intent? How is it defined?
- What happens if the intent is not in the input?

Okay, even if we don't talk about "intent" and just want to extract the main meaning,

- what exactly is meaning of the sentence, is it just extracting the "important words"? If so, what makes the words "important"? How is "important" defined?
- Are only non-stop words not important? If so, then you can simply remove stopwords, e.g. [Stopword removal with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk). And also, what then are stopwords?

## But I heard people doing it with dependency parsing

**What is dependency parsing?**

- https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/15.pdf
- http://nlpprogress.com/english/dependency_parsing.html
- https://paperswithcode.com/task/dependency-parsing

In short, it provides a structured representation of text. But non of the structure in traditional dependency formalism has notion of "intent".

**Proof:** CTR + F on https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/15.pdf

So I don't think just simply parsing the text with dependency trees would help unless the notion of "intent" is better defined in your scenario.

## How about this SpaCy tool that trains a model for intent?

From https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_intent_parser.py

Yes, that's an example of using a combination parsing labels and sequence labeling and defining that as "intent", more specifically, we see examples from https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_intent_parser.py#L31

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    (
        "find a cafe with great wifi",
        {
            "heads": [0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 2],  # index of token head
            "deps": ["ROOT", "-", "PLACE", "-", "QUALITY", "ATTRIBUTE"],
        },
    ),
    (
        "find a hotel near the beach",
        {
            "heads": [0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 2],
            "deps": ["ROOT", "-", "PLACE", "QUALITY", "-", "ATTRIBUTE"],
        },
    ),
```

Each training data is made up of

1. text
2. the index of the dependency head
3. the "intent" labels related to the dependency head

And an example in/outputs from https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_intent_parser.py#L173

```
[in]:  find a hotel with good wifi
[out]:
    [
      ('find', 'ROOT', 'find'),
      ('hotel', 'PLACE', 'find'),
      ('good', 'QUALITY', 'wifi'),
      ('wifi', 'ATTRIBUTE', 'hotel')
    ]
```

The example above shows that the whole list of triplets are defined as an intent, rather than just the raw strings. The triplets refers to the `(dependent, relation, head)`, e.g. the `hotel` is the `PLACE` to `find` from the triplets `('hotel', 'PLACE', 'find')`.

**Note:** This is solely SpaCy notion of "semantics" or "intent" which is not wrong but well-defined and hence a model to perform this task is trainable in a supervised machine learning paradigm. Details, see  https://spacy.io/usage/examples

Depending on how and what you define as intent/semantics, the in/outputs will change and the model to train may be different.

## But why do you have to make it so complicated, I just want the intent string?!

Because what does "main meaning" or "intent" mean if it's just a string?

We go back to the lack of definition that makes the task a magical one rather than one that computers can perform.

Comment: Very good (and short) description of fairly complex topic. For the minimal 'intent' of a sentence you could explore dependency parsing using Subject-Verb-Object model. It's quick & dirty but works fairly well on corpus of similar documents (a lot depends on what kind of language your documents represent).